# Julia makedir dir.create Is there a way to create directories in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to create a bunch of directories which is pretty straightforward in Python and R. Does anyone know how to do this in Julia? I looking at the Julia manual and nothing jumped out at me. Thanks.
Chase CB

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `mkdir`.  From the [Julia Language documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.mkdir):

> Make a new directory with name path and permissions mode. mode defaults to 0o777, modified by the current file creation mask. This function never creates more than one directory. If the directory already exists, or some intermediate directories do not exist, this function throws an error. See mkpath for a function which creates all required intermediate directories. Return path.

Comment: One can also use the `mkpath`
"Create all directories in the given path, with permissions mode. mode defaults to 0o777, modified by the current file creation mask. Return path."

Comment: Should note that mkpath does not error out if the file path already exists